# Как убрать строчку"Комментарии отключены" на главной сайта?

Tags: html, wordpress

Сайт - pirogi.su
CMS - Wordpress. 
Не могу понять,в каком файле нужно убрать строку за отображение данной строчки...

Answer (score 3):

На сколько я понимаю тут на главную выводится лента новостей. Если там должен быть просто текст то логичнее сделать статическую главную страницу (в админке «внешний вид», «настройки», «статическая главная страница») и выбери там предварительно созданную страницу с нужным текстом.